# Moving a domain and staging url

Tags: domains, subdomain

I have a website with web hosting I am planning on switching away from (Windows Server).

So I got a hosting plan with a linux server and I was going to build a site there using Perch CMS.

Right now I have a temporary domain (minus a real domain name) at
http://gator1784.hostgator.com/~elaine/perch/

However Perch does not recommend using a temporary domain with a tilde (~elaine), what should I do? What are my options?

I would just like to build this site on the new server and not have too many issues when I switch the domain over.

The current website has to remain live for now (on the other server which is windows) while I build the current site on a linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it currently work with the ~elaine? (Your login page loaded fine and a Google for known issues didn't find anything)

Certainly keeping it that way would be bad form, but for development I would imagine so long as the CMS works I wouldn't worry too much about it.

If you REALLY have to use a domain name, you should hook it up and edit your Apache settings (or whichever Webserver you are using) to only allow access via your IP address.

Comment: Good point. They say it's "bad form" in the sense I am probably going to have to go into my database and rewrite all the '~/elaines' out of it once I migrate my domain over...

Comment: That will be a pain, but I would advise doing a DB dump and using a text editor to do a find and replace, normally takes some of the headache out of it.